# when closing the connection to sql server with c#?

Tags: c#, sql-server

```
public void addRow( string[] values)
{
    string addrow = "INSERT INTO " + tableName + " VALUES ( ' ";

    for (int i = 0; i < values.Length; i++)
    {
        addrow += values[i] + "' ";

        if (i == values.Length - 1)
            break;

        addrow += " ,' ";
    }

    addrow += " )";

    createConnection();

    sqlcmd = new SqlCommand(addrow, sqlcon);
    sqlcmd.Connection.Open();
    sqlcmd.BeginExecuteNonQuery();
    //sqlcmd.Connection.Close();
}
```

This method in my class `SqlCmds` supposed to add new row to my local database but when closing the connection no thing happens to my database I have to leave the connection open to add the new row what should I do ?

thanks in advance :D */

Comment: You are missing the `EndExecuteNonQuery`, or could you just use `ExecuteNonQuery`?

Comment: In addition to sqlcmd.ExecuteNonQuery() as stated by Matt and Austin, you should *REALLY* look into a SQL command with parameters to protect against SQL injection.

Comment: you need to wrap the `sqlcmd.ExecuteNonQuery` around a `try{}catch(SqlException sqlEx){}` do not assume that your code will not throw errors

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's do it right:

```
public void addRow (string[] values) {
  // Validate public methods arguments 
  if (null == values)
    throw new ArgumentNullException("values"); 

  // Make the query parametrized: it's faster and not prone to SQL injection 
  // Do not append String in a loop; use Join instead
  string sql = string.Format("INSERT INTO {0} VALUES ({1})",
    tableName, 
    string.Join(", ", values.Select((item, index) => "@param_" + index.ToString()));

  // wrap IDisposable into using
  // let createConnection() return the connection created 
  using (var con = createConnection()) {
    con.Open();

    // wrap IDisposable into using
    using (var cmd = new SqlCommand(sql, con)) {
      // Parametrized query: parameters assigning
      for (int index = 0; index < values.Length; ++index)
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@param_" + index.ToString(), values[i]); 

      // Finally query executing
      cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 7):

Try

```
sqlcmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
```

You should also consider wrapping the disposable objects in a using statement to let it handle closing/disposing of your objects.

Comment: 1'd for using statement.

Comment: thank you so much that solved the problem but can anyone explain why it works when using ExecuteNonQuery() not BeginExecuteNonQuery() or what the difference between the tow methods